# suhosin not allowing increase within limit

Tags: php

I am getting a lot of the following error messages in my `/var/log/syslog`:

```
May 27 10:29:58 ********* suhosin[30143]: ALERT - script tried to increase memory_limit to 2145386496 bytes which is above the allowed value (attacker 'REMOTE_ADDR not set', file 'unknown')
```

My `memory_limit` and my `suhosin.memory_limit` are both set to `3072M`

Why is suhosin not allowing an increase to 2145386496 bytes (2046M) which is below both the set memory_limit and the set suhosin.memory_limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the memory limit as proposed appears to be working fine with PHP 5.5.15 and Suhosin extension 0.9.36 an a 64bit machine.
Suhosin's support for memory limits > 2GB was added with Version 0.9.32 in 2010.

Proof of concept:

```
php -d suhosin.memory_limit=3072M -d memory_limit=3072M -d suhosin.log.sapi=2 -r "ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');"

php -d suhosin.memory_limit=3072M -d memory_limit=3072M -d suhosin.log.sapi=2 -r "ini_set('memory_limit', '4048M');"
ALERT - script tried to increase memory_limit to 4244635648 bytes which is above the allowed value (attacker 'REMOTE_ADDR not set', file 'Command line code', line 1)
```